# Star Rating System label highlighting based on check box

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a star rating system which is built with the help of checkboxes(Hidden).

The rating system has N/A as a first selection option.

Now I can show N/A or No parking sigh as red color when selecting the label.

But I am unable to change the color of this N/A when I select other stars. 
because when I rate one star or 3.5 star rating, the red is also highlighted which was part of the previous CSS mechanism which I had just changed the 1st star to N/A option.

How can I keep the red color selection if I select N/A, also when I select any stars I should show the N/A in a different color or gray(unselected) because it's not part of star ratings but just N/A.

```
.rate {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .rate>input {
        display: none;
    }
    .rate>label {
        float: right;
        color: #b4b3b3;
    }
    .rate>label:before {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 3em;
        padding: .3rem .2rem;
        margin: 0 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        content: "\f005 ";
    }
    .rate>label:last-child:before {
        content: "\f05e";
        //color: #cc5858;
        margin-right: 10px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        border-right: .08em solid #4a90e2;
    }
    .rate .half:before {
        content: "\f089 ";
        position: absolute;
        padding-right: 0;
    }
    input:checked~label,
    label:hover,
    label:hover~label {
        color: #ffcd00;
    }
    input:checked+label:hover,
    input:checked~label:hover,
    input:checked~label:hover~label,
    label:hover~input:checked~label {
        color: rgb(255, 224, 85);
    }
    input:checked~label:last-child:before {
        color: #cc5858;
    }
    input:checked+input:last-child:not(:checked)~label:last-child {
        color: #14ff4e !important;
    }
```

Angular Code below

```
<fieldset class="rate" id="rate-{{controlIndex}}" [class.readonly]="readonly">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let star of ratings; let i = index">
        <input type="radio" id="rating-{{ratings.length-i-1}}-{{controlIndex}}" name="rating-{{controlIndex}}" [checked]="(star.id == rating)" />
        <label [class.half]="(i%2)==1" for="rating-{{ratings.length-i-1}}-{{controlIndex}}" (click)="updateRating(star.id)"></label>
    </ng-container> </fieldset>
```

- The image is for illustration purpose only

[image]

Comment: Please provide the HTML code as well.

Comment: Added the HTML Code in the Edited post.